# Como ordenar uma Lista de Lista de strings?

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq, lista

Tenho uma `List<List<string>>` e preciso ordenar a lista principal de acordo com alguns elementos da secundária veja a ilustração abaixo.

[image: listas]

Eu preciso que no primeiro nível fique em ordem alfabética, e no segundo nível fique em ordem crescente mas de acordo com os números. Por exemplo o número 26 tem que vir antes de 1000.

O código abaixo faz algo semelhante porem no segundo nível ele ordena de acordo com a `string`, então o 1000 vem antes do 26.

```
var MySortedList = MyUnsortedList.OrderBy( x => x[1] ).ThenBy( x => x[2] );
```

Eu teria que convertê-lo em int e fazer a ordenação porem em algumas *strings* eu tenho `/` e `-`. Nesse caso teria uma `Exception`. Não tenho ideia de como implementá-lo.

[image: Tela da aplicação]

Comment: E como deve ser tratado esses dados? Eles não são números, eles contém dígitos numéricos, que é bem diferente. Sem um critério do que deve fazer, qualquer solução é errada, e o critério correto nós não sabemos, só você sabe.

Comment: Todos os dados são strings. Porem esses dados são apresentados em um ListView. Pra ficar mais fácil para o usuário encontrar o elemento eu preciso ordena-los. Então no primeiro nível aparece em ordem alfabética. A, B, C ... Acessando "A". Eu preciso que ele mostre os números em ordem crescente. 1,2,3,4.... O números com / e - podemos considerar apenas a primeira parte da string com um split('/') ou split('-'). Não sei se fui muito claro.

Comment: E porque não fez esse `split()`?

Comment: Então eu posso fazer o split, porem eu não sei como implementar o split('/'), split('-'). Converter em int e implementar no código acima. Pra ele ordenar os números em ordem crescente.

Comment: Postei uma imagem do meu listView. Veja que no segundo nível não está em ordem numérica.

Comment: Idealmente seria melhor se tivesse um código para que pudéssemos testar. Você pode garantir que todos elementos começam com números válidos?

Comment: No momento alguns poucos começam com A, AM, C. Mas caso não tenha outro jeito eu posso eliminar esses dados da lista.

Comment: Precisa decidir o que fazer com esse casos. O problema todo não é o código, é a falta de critério de como resolver esses casos.

Comment: Veja no na imagem do listView. Eu preciso que a primeira parte dos números apareçam em ordem numérica e não de string como esta. E preciso implementar isso na ordenação do código que postei como exemplo.

Comment: E o que faz com esses casos que são letras?

Comment: Eles ficam no final da lista como está acontecendo agora.

Comment: Em ordem alfabética?

Comment: Sim. Isso mesmo.

Comment: Qual é a quantidade máxima de dígitos que pode ter antes da primeira barra? O que está depois da barra não importa?

Comment: A quantidade antes da barra é indeterminada. Eu preciso ordenar só o que está antes da barra. O que está depois tanto faz a ordem.

Comment: Não tem um máximo? Pode ter 1 milhão de dígitos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso provavelmente dará certo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var lista = new List<string> { "12/10", "01/02", "123/12", "A/1", "4/5" };
        var listaClassificada = lista.OrderBy(x => ConversaoParcial(x));
        listaClassificada.ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }
    public static string ConversaoParcial(string texto) {
        int valor;
        string textoParcial = texto.Split('/', '-')[0];
        return int.TryParse(textoParcial, out valor) ? textoParcial.PadLeft(4, '0') : textoParcial.PadLeft(4, 'A');
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/rsvvPn). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gLqzgS).  Também [coloquei no GitHub para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/SplitAndConvert.cs).

- [Documentação do `Split()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_String_Split_System_Char___)
- [Documentação do `PadLeft()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_String_PadLeft_System_Int32_System_Char_)
- [Documentação do `TryParse()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__)

Comment: Olá bigown, muito obrigado pela sua ajuda. Consegui fazer a implementação que eu queria. Muito obrigado. Valeu mesmo.